# Literature on the advantages of using an auto-encoder for classification

Tags: classification, reference-request, autoencoders, supervised-learning, transfer-learning

Given a supervised problem with X, y input pairs, one can do two things for obtaining the function f that maps X with y with Neural Networks (and in general in machine learning):

- Deploy directly a supervised learning algorithm that maps X to y
- Deploy a (variational) auto-encoder for learning useful features, and then using these for training the supervised learning algorithm

I would like to be pointed to some papers/blogs that explain which technique is better and when or where they conduct empirical benchmarking experiments.

Comment: Are you asking about the advantages of using auto-encoders to pre-train models in an unsupervised way that are later trained in a supervised way to solve a classification task? You mention variational auto-encoders. Are you interested specifically in VAEs or any AE?

Comment: Yes exactly, AE or VAE is the same